# Submit Button validation not happening in JS. Undefined formGroupExampleInput

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display two alerts in a simple form. One, if any field is empty other on successful submission. This is a simple form for learning purpose.
    It is now showing error that 'Undefined formGroupExampleInput'
    Please Help so that the validation can be done.
    Thanks in advance.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mycss.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to MAC Library!!</h1>
        <h2>Registration Page</h2>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">GROUP 4</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="index0.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href = "about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href = "myacct.html">My Account</a></li>
      <li><a href = "register.html">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</br>
</br>

<h3 class="myh3">Sign up as new user to receive email updates about upcoming events in the city</h3>        

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm()
{
             if(document.form1.formGroupExampleInput.value==""||
                document.form1.formGroupExampleInput2.value==""||
                document.form1.exampleInputEmail1.value==""||
                document.form1.exampleInputPassword1.value==""){
          alert("Enter all fields");
    }

    else{         
     document.forms["form1"].submit();
     alert("Your Form Successfully Submitted");
   }
}
</script>
        <div>
        <form id="form1">
        document.form1.formGroupExampleInput.value
   <fieldset class="form-group">
   <div class="required">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Enter your first name">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="required">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Enter your last name">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="required">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" required="required" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small class="text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="required">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" required="required" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </fieldset>


  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <label>Gender</label>
<div class="radio">    
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
      Male
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
      Female
    </label>
  </div>   
  </fieldset> 

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"     onclick="submitForm();">Submit</button>


</form>`enter code here`
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried placing the script before the closing `</body>` tag?

Comment: ye they might not have been created yet, does using `document.getElementById(id);` make any difference rather than referencing them directly too?

Comment: As said above, place the `<script>` before the closing `</body>` tag. Also, you'll want to access the forms either by using `var form1 = document.getElementsById("form1")` or `document.forms.form1`. "form1" itself is not a property of the `document` object

Comment: document.getElementById(id) This worked like a charm.. Thank you so much all of you.